# Loading webpage from local path iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview

I have been trying to load a saved webpage without adding the file to the project directly. 
I have been trying something like this:

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"/Users/Virtual-OSX/Desktop/website/files"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest * requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

The urlAddress is not being found can anyone help with this. Like I said I want to avoid dragging the file into the project.

Dope... found my answer after I stopped reading and tried experimenting I found I can just let

```
NSString *urlAddress = /Users/Virtual-OSX/Desktop/website/files/index.html
```

Comment: can you check the path you given.. is it correct.. path show file loads from desktop.. its not from the bundle.. Try to check the file exists in that path..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. the path was correct but I just needed to let the string equal the path no need for anything else :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```